# Silverlight Mouse Events: MouseEnter and MouseLeave conflicts

Tags: silverlight, events, animation, silverlight-4.0, mouseevent

I have a collection of buttons in a grid. For each one of these buttons, I want to handle the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to animate the height of the button (and do some other *interesting* stuff). It all works good until I start moving my mouse too fast over and off the buttons which eventually cause the events to take place at before the other is complete. What's the best way of making sure the events wait for eachother before being triggered?

**UPDATE:**

Going by x0r's advice, I refactored my code into an internal class which inherits from `Button` and has the required methods to perform the animations. Unfortunately, this did not really solve the problem because *- I think -* I'm handling the `Completed` event of the first animation in two separate places. (correct me if I'm wrong). Here's my code:

```
internal class MockButton : Button
{
    #region Fields

    private Storyboard _mouseEnterStoryBoard;
    private Storyboard _mouseLeaveStoryBoard;
    private Double _width;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    internal Int32 Index { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Ctors

    internal MockButton(Int32 index) : this(index, 200)
    {

    }

    internal MockButton(Int32 index, Double width)
    {
        this.Index = index;
        this._width = width;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    internal void OnMouseEnter(Action action, Double targetAnimationHeight)
    {
        if (_mouseEnterStoryBoard == null)
        {
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            heightAnimation.From = 10;
            heightAnimation.To = targetAnimationHeight;
            heightAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Height"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, this);
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);
        }
        _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            action.Invoke();
        };
        _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Begin();
    }

    internal void OnMouseLeave()
    {
        if (_mouseLeaveStoryBoard == null)
        {
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            heightAnimation.To = 10;
            heightAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Height"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, this);
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);
        }
        if (_mouseEnterStoryBoard.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Stopped)
        {
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.Begin();
            };
        }
        else
        {
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.Begin();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Some events are getting triggered multiple times.  An example of that is the `Click` event on the close button of my `Rule` object...

```
    public Rule(Action<Int32> closeAction)
    {
        this.Style = Application.Current.Resources["RuleDefaultStyle"] as Style;
        this.CloseAction = closeAction;
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (_closeButton != null)
            {
                _closeButton.Click += (btn, args) =>
                {
                    if (this.CloseAction != null)
                    {
                        this.CloseAction.Invoke(this.Index);
                    }
                };
                if (_closeButtonShouldBeVisible)
                {
                    _closeButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And below is the `Action<Int32>` I'm passing to the `Rule` object as the `CloseAction`:

```
    private void RemoveRule(Int32 ruleIndex)
    {
        Rule ruleToRemove = Rules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Index.Equals(ruleIndex));
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
        animation.From = 1;
        animation.To = 0;
        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, ruleToRemove);
        sb.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (Rules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Index.Equals(ruleIndex)) != null)
            {
                this.Rules.RemoveAt(ruleIndex);
            }
        };
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

**UPDATE 3:**

In order to avoid the animations running too early, I thought I could delay the `MouseEnter` event, so if the user just scrolls over the item too fast, it doesn't kick off. But I have a problem now: Say the user mouses over the item and then mouses out. If I use the `Storyboard.BeginTime` property, that won't safe guard against that behavior because eventhough the animation gets delayed, it's still going to start eventually... So is there a way I could prevent that from happening?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

check in your `mouseleave` eventhandler if the first storyboard is still running and if that is the case attach the starting of the second storyboard to the `Completed` event of the first storybaord:

```
private void OnOddRowMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    if(_firstStoryboard.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Stopped)
        _firstStoryboard.Completed += (s,e) =>   _secondStoryboard.Begin();
    else
        _secondStoryboard.Begin()
```

Comment: I've updated the question, could you take a look at it please? Thank you.

Comment: @Kassem: how does your code behave (what is not working as it should?) btw: you probably should also check in MouseEnter if the MouseLeave storyboard is still running and if that is the case stop the MouseLeave storyboard

Comment: I still couldn't understand why I'm having these issues. One thing I noticed is that several events are being triggered multiple times when they should be called only once! An example of that is the click event of the close button (check the new update).

Comment: @Kassem: events are only fired once, could it be that you attach the event handlers more than once? Your code seems fine but you should check by making a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Everything that Silverlight does is asyncronous and so most likely what is happening is that because you are moving quickly in and out of the box the mouse leave is being fired before the mouseenter has a chance to finish. You could setup your two events so thay they have an indicator of whether or not the other is in process. For example you could do this

```
bool mouseOut =false;
bool mouseIn =false;

void OnMouseEnter(Action action, Double targetAnimationHeight)
{
    if(!this.mouseOut)
    {
        this.mouseIn = true;

        if (_mouseEnterStoryBoard == null)
        {
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            heightAnimation.From = 10;
            heightAnimation.To = targetAnimationHeight;
            heightAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Height"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, this);
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);
        }
        _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            action.Invoke();
        };
        _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Begin();

        if(this.mouseOut)
        {
            this.OnMouseLeave();
        }

        this.mouseIn = false;
    }
}

void OnMouseLeave()
{
    if(!this.mouseIn)
    {
        this.mouseOut = false;

        if (_mouseLeaveStoryBoard == null)
        {
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            heightAnimation.To = 10;
            heightAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Height"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, this);
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);
        }
        if (_mouseEnterStoryBoard.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Stopped)
        {
            _mouseEnterStoryBoard.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.Begin();
            };
        }
        else
        {
            _mouseLeaveStoryBoard.Begin();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.mouseOut = true;
    }
}
```

I haven't actually checked this code but this should help you to at least get closer to what you want. This should be quick enough that your user doesn't realize that it is not firing exactly on exit if they go over it quickly. But this should help to keep you from getting overlap.

Another way you could do this is setup the initial events as null, and have the mouse in event set the mouse in event when it is complete but the problem with that is that if the mouse out fires before the event is set then you don't event get the event firing.